# Shield Attack Glitch. macOS Minecraft glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I recently got Minecraft on macOS. I found out it can be difficult to use but I thought I could work around it. However, I found out that whenever I attack, I hold up a shield, no matter how hard I try the shield comes up. I've tried finding how to change this in controls but find no way. Please help

Comment: I don’t think this is a mac issue, as Java works on tons of platforms (I could be wrong). Also, have you made sure all your drivers are up to date? Do you have this problem with any other software?

Comment: Is your mouse a standard mouse?  Or is it a mouse from Mac (some of the ones from apple have one button)?

Comment: Could be a strange interaction with the right click on the Mac's default mouse.